# How can I remap Menu to Meta key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg

I want to remap my Menu key to a meta key, so I can use it in keyboard shortcuts for applications and whatnot.  The closest I've come is going into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`, and changing;

```
key <MENU> {    [ Menu      ]   };
```

to

```
key <MENU> {    [ Meta_R    ]   };
```

The problem is, when I make keyboard shortcuts, it will recognize the key as `Meta_R`, but when I type it along with another key (<kbd>G</kbd> for example), it changes the shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Once menu key becomes meta then you want a shortcut like meta+g as a shortcut?